# How do you optimize an organo-metalic compound containing cerium in in Gaussian?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, software, organometallic-compounds, basis-set

I am trying to perform optimisation of the molecule attached. I need to get partial charges and frequencies. The issue is that it doesn't converge with following input:

```
%nprocshared=8
%mem=16GB
%chk=CTB.chk
#n opt b3lyp/gen pop=(ReadRadii, savechelpg) SCF=QC
CTB
0 2
Ce -6.41954 5.21611 0.61820
...
N -4.38490 3.87720 0.35349

H -5.52145 4.13584 -2.66372
Ce 0
SDD
****
H Si C N 0
6-31G
****
Ce 2.88
```

As well I get error message:
Restarting incremental Fock formation.
Gradient too large for Newton-Raphson or scaled steepest descent --
use steepest descent instead.

[image]

Comment: Hello, it is necessary to add the keywords "pseudo=read" after "b3lyp/gen" because you use pseudopotential SDD. Moreover, I would suggest to use "scf=xqc".

Comment: Baffled by the negative vote. Seems to me to be a perfectly valid question.

Comment: It's hard to know your problem with convergence without seeing more of the output (e.g., how the SCF progressed). I agree that XQC is a good idea, but I'd actually suggest starting by minimizing your compound with [xtb](https://xtb-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contents.html) an approximate method from the Grimme group that generally provides good starting geometries and usually converges more easily.

Comment: Other options to try and find a better starting geometry and save time: simplify the ligands to $\ce{N(SiH3)2}$ or even $\ce{NH2}$, use a GGA such as PBE for a pre-optimization. As a side-note, use a modern dispersion correction.

Comment: With a little more detail, this question would likely be well text on the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/)